# How to match cell value to sheet name then return value based on that

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to match cell value to sheet name then return value based on that. How can i do that?

For example, there are 2 column (A and B)

If the value in range A1:A5 = other sheet name
Then return cell value of column B in that other sheet name

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If A2 in Sheet1 contains the formula, and B2 contains the sheet name "Sheet2", this will fetch the value in Sheet2!A2:

```
=INDIRECT(B2&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

To get the value in Sheet2!B2 instead, you can add 1 to `COLUMN()`:

```
=INDIRECT(B2&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1))
```

### Explanation:

- `INDIRECT` returns the value stored in a cell using some text formatted as a standard cell reference such as "A2", or "Sheet2!$A$2". Now we will try to generate that text automatically.
- `ADDRESS(row, col)` converts cell and column numbers to a standard cell reference in text format. ADDRESS(1,1) returns "$A$1", and so on.
- `ROW()` returns the number of the row the formula sits in, and `COLUMN()` for the column number. Since the formula is in A2, `ROW()` will equal 2 and `COLUMN()` will equal 1. These are just plain numbers, so we can add 1 to the column number to get B instead of A. We give those numbers to `ADDRESS(2,2)` to get "$B$2".
- We append this address to the sheet name we want that is in B2: `B2&!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())`, not forgetting the exclamation mark between, to obtain the full cell reference we need: "Sheet2!$B$2"
- Last step, we provide that text to `INDIRECT`, which will go and fetch the value at that address.